# Using original URL request for proxied HttpServlet Request

Tags: java, servlets, request, servlet-filters

I have an Apache proxy which redirects requests to /foo/bar to a web app running on /foo. The problem is that I have a Servlet filter in my filter chain which requires the request to still be in the /foo/bar format. It is an authentication filter I can't change and this is resulting in incorrect redirects after login to /foo instead of /foo/bar.

Following other similar threads, I've attempted using RequestDispatcher.forward with a modified request and HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect to modify the URL. The first approach seems to skip the rest of my filter chain, and the second goes to the proxy which then modifies the URL back to /foo.

Is there any way around this. Ideally what I'd like is for just the authentication filter to get a /foo/bar request and the rest of the chain to get a /foo request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like HttpServletRequestWrapper was what I was looking for. Just needed to extend this and provide getRequestURI and getRequestURL overrides (rather like [described here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/web_admin_servlet_filters.htm)). Then needed to add filter mappings before and after my auth filter to convert the request URL/URI as needed.